# Cluster IP Services configured in Helm sub charts are caused timeouts if running from same pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I tried to integrated Helm sub charts and use these sub charts as cluster IP Service within the cluster. But accessing the services within a pod causes a timeout. Without using sub charts it works. Tried with minikube and Docker for Desktop.

**Test scenario**

```
helm create app
helm create sub-app
```

Change Chart.yml of app

```
dependencies:
- name: sub-app
  version: 0.1.0
  repository: file://../sub-app
```

Go to 'app' directory and run:

```
helm dep update
```

Causes sub-app-0.1.0.tgz generated under charts.

Run install helm:

```
helm install app-test app --create-namespace --namespace app-test --wait
```

** Check for services **

Set namespace current

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=app-test
```

Check for services (kubectl get services -o wide):

```
app-test           ClusterIP   10.100.32.99   <none>        80/TCP    5m14s   
app.kubernetes.io/instance=app-test,app.kubernetes.io/name=app
app-test-sub-app   ClusterIP   **10.96.246.19**   <none>        80/TCP    5m14s   
app.kubernetes.io/instance=app-test,app.kubernetes.io/name=sub-app
```

Check for sub app endpoints:

```
app-test           172.17.0.8:80   6m30s
app-test-sub-app   172.17.0.4:80   6m30s
```

Check for pods:

```
app-test-684c75bb-8d8lr            1/1     Running   0          8m51s   172.17.0.8   minikube   <none>           <none>
app-test-sub-app-c4cc76d6d-2t8mv   1/1     Running   0          8m51s   172.17.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

So it looks all good, I have a cluster IP and from the pod I should be able to access the service via the cluster DNS or cluster IP:

Open terminal for POD app (install curl btw)

```
curl http://10.96.246.19 --> works
```

Open terminal for POD sub-app

```
curl http://10.96.246.19 --> timeout
```

Comment: Maybe a network policy? try run a `kubectl get networkpolicy`